# Can MaintenanceTrigger fire a Toast event?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

My goal to have a task running every 15 mins, even if my program is not started, and have a Toast message if I have to "say" something by the program.

I made Declaration for Background Task, with System Event. The Entry Point is "GS.MT".

I created a namespace called GS, then a class MT, what is IBackgroundTask.

```
namespace GS
{
  public sealed class MT : IBackgroundTask
  {
    async public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
      BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
      var toast = NotificationsExtensions.ToastContent.ToastContentFactory.CreateToastText01();
      toast.TextBodyWrap.Text = "FUT!";
      Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast.CreateNotification());
      deferral.Complete();
    }
  }
}
```

I register this with this code:

```
  string triggernév = string.Format("{0} MT", "GS");
  BackgroundTask.EltávolításNévAlapján(triggernév); //remove if exists
  Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.MaintenanceTrigger trigger = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.MaintenanceTrigger(15, false);
  BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
  builder.Name = triggernév;
  builder.TaskEntryPoint = "GS.MT";
  builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
  builder.Register();
```

My code runs, my task is registred, but it will never show the toast message. **How can I show the Toast message from the Maintenance trigger's run?**

Comment: Roast a toast? lol.. did you maybe mean execute a toast, or show a toast?

Comment: Actually my brain got roasted already from googling around. I can not belive that this simple code can not work somewhy... of course I ment to "fire a toast event".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned if you have refrenced background task in the main project, and as it is not working it is the most likely cause.